# What should a student do immedately after he or she is accepted into a graduate program

Tags: graduate-school, academic-life

Can someone provide advise as to what a student should do immediately after being accepted into a graduate program and has identified with a professor?

Usually students are accepted in the middle of their final year of undergrad. A window of time opens between now and when the first semester begins.

I wonder what should a student optimally do during this time to smoothly transit into the designated graduate program.

Some thoughts:

1. Build up relationships with other graduate students, professors
2. Start reading papers on the topic of focus
3. Start preparing course work for first year of graduate school
4. Start identifying specific research area and pin point thesis topic and open questions
5. Get to know the locale

But ultimately this question is directed at people who have went through this process. What can a student do now in the little time that he or she has to smoothly enter the graduate program?

Comment: Go out for a very nice dinner with your friends and family members to celebrate.

Comment: okay maybe not that immediate ;)

Comment: What country is this?  In the US, I would say 1,3,4 are done after graduate school starts.  4, much after.  Maybe 1 is a good idea, but if you do not already live near there, that can wait until school starts also.

Comment: @GEdgar, I think you mean to say that in the US 1,3 and 4 CAN be done after graduate school starts, but there is no reason not to start ahead of time. 1 and 3 can be started easily(even if you don't live close by, it wouldn't be a bad idea to E-mail a few people in your future department) 4, you should be careful about doing too early... If you do pick a specific research area, don't let it be set into stone, be flexible with it, as it may change COMPLETELY once you start school.

Comment: Some professors allow you to start during the summer, which can achieve all of the points on your list.

Comment: Find a place to live. Make packing/moving lists. If you're switching countries, get a visa arranged.

Comment: You should consider whether other programs you have submitted applications to will make you a better offer.

Comment: I hold a master's degree, two post-master's degrees and a doctorate. Trust me illegal, I ain't no rocket scientist. I would suggest you congratulate yourself earning a bachelor's degree and take pride in your acceptance into graduate school. Perhaps I am immune to the seriousness of graduate school, but many people I know, myself included, actually found graduate school in some ways EASIER than undergraduate. Perhaps taking the attitude that the "work" simply has to be done, it gets done. Just do it. I worked throughout both my undergraduate and graduate studies, sometimes part-time,.........

Comment: ..............sometimes full-time. My grades took a hit but I personally did not care. I was not working towards academic excellence, rather my goal was career/professional. If your goal is the same, I'd concern myself with planning for what to do AFTER graduate school. Many employers look not just at grades but on work experience as well. So find yourself a job, keep up with your studies and enjoy. what should you do before starting graduate school? In my opinion, remember you have to first graduate college. Work during summer, take a trip, hang out with buddies, have fun. And most of all....

Comment: .....become legal immigrant and HAVE FUN!!! Good luck to you.

Comment: I think some of the suggestions I got about publishing are relevant: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5711/things-to-do-before-submitting-a-manuscript

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have three utterly contradictory pieces of advice:

1. The first year of graduate school will be a much more intense version of the coursework that you took as an undergraduate. In particular, the basic core courses often sink many first year students. For example, in some disciplines you may be asked to read over 1000 pages a week during that first semester, while in others you might be asked to do significantly more complex problem sets or labs than you've ever encountered previously.  If you can, I'd obtain copies of the syllabi for the required first year classes and start reading as much of the material as you can. The more breathing space you can give yourself that first semester the better. Build up your scholarly reserve.
2. Graduate school is a very long haul. Burnout is a very real possibility. Because you don't have a gap year, you should use your summer to expand your mind a bit. Go for a month or so of walkabout in Europe or Australia. Take what will be your last extended vacation for a little while. Build up your emotional/psychological reserves.
3. Unless you're in a well-funded program, you may well be destitute -- especially before you pick up a TA/RA position. Even with funding, you may only make $15-25,000 a year, which can be very hard to live on. You might want to build up your savings heading into grad school so that you don't have to take out too many loans or spend too many cold nights eating ramen noodles. Build up your financial reserves.

Comment: So sell fake watches on the street of Paris while breath in "astrobiology for the graduate student" :)

Comment: This! I took an industry job to do #3 of RoboKaren's advice and also studied a bit off and on to pass a preliminary exam before I walked in.

Focus on not burning out. I know it's a exciting time, but it's important to remember it's not just about a head start.

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify what field(s) this applies to - because, for instance, in my field (mathematics), neither #1 nor #3 are quite applicable.  (No "history of discipline", 1000 pages of mathematics per week would be absurd, and TA/RA funding is pretty much universal for PhD students.)  #2 is, though.

Comment: @NateEldredge - what *do* maths students study in their first year and is it possible to do pre-studying over the summer?  It must also be nice to be able to fully fund everyone. I guess this is an artifact of having required math courses for the undergraduates that require boatloads of TAs. Even then, I can't imagine your grad students make more than $25,000 a year, which is poverty level.

Comment: @RoboKaren: You can probably get a good sense by flipping open your own institution's graduate catalog to the "Mathematics" section :-) programs are pretty standardized.  Usually real/complex analysis, abstract algebra, and 1-2 other courses.  One certainly can pre-study and it's a good idea, though often it's even more productive to thoroughly review undergraduate-level material.  History of Mathematics is, for better or for worse, often considered a niche subfield of math,  and it's rare for it to be required at the graduate level (if offered at all).

Comment: My point is the spirit rather than the letter of the answer. #1 - try to pre-study. #2 try to relax. and #3 even if you are fully funded, it won't be enough. Build up some cash.

Comment: I agree with the spirit of your suggestions and just wanted to mention that the specifics can vary.  One of the things I like best about this site is learning that aspects of academia I had always considered universal can actually vary widely between disciplines/countries/etc. To continue on my theme, in case anyone is interested: A moderately dense page of mathematics can easily take an hour or more to read and fully digest, so 1000 pages per week is out of the question; I'd say 40-50 is a more plausible average.  Much more time is spent solving exercises.

Comment: Amended as suggested. :-)

Comment: It *is* nice to support everyone and lower-level service courses are a huge part of that.  $25,000 (9 months) is about right for wealthy private institutions, publics more like $20,000 or less.  For students who are single and live simply it tends to be sufficient.

Comment: It might also be good to mention that the salaries of PhD students are not nearly this bad everywhere. My impressions is that those places where being a PhD student is actually a job (as in, you are employed), the salaries are decent enough to live on (though still not anywhere near competitive with industry).

Comment: Because the OP is an undergraduate and going straight into a graduate program, we can safely assume she is not in Tobias' hypothetical situation.

Comment: I am not sure how you rule it out based on that. Yes, the most likely case is that the student is American, but it is also possible to go straight from undergraduate to PhD other places (e.g. Aarhus in Denmark).

Comment: I agree with @TobiasKildetoft. This is a very good answer, but quite US centric. I suggest indicating it explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

Talk to a lot of graduate students, especially in the lab(s) you are interested in.  If necessary, cold-email them and ask about their experiences in the PhD program.  There will be time to talk to graduate students during visit weekend, but you won't get enough time to have a lot of in-depth conversations, and in general the department will put on its best face for you.  (It will mostly be the happy students who bother to show up at visit weekend.)

You don't want to accept an offer only to realize it was not quite what you'd expected.  There are usually things that seem like no big deal during visit weekend, but are actually a huge pain in the ass, and you want to be warned of that early.

Answer (score 1):

As a PhD student in engineering, I can say that the most important initial task is to build relationships with your peers and especially your supervisor. The stronger your academic relationships, the better your foundation of support will be. This will especially come in handy when you need help, either academically or personally.

Also.... read.... a lot.... My trick is to setup a Google Scholar alerts system that forwards relevant articles to a special Gmail tag, for me to read at my own convenience.